# Post json object with php(http post)?

Tags: php, json

I need to post json object with http post request and to handle responses.

json object :

```
{
   "my_json" : "12345" 
}
```

I wrote somethinh like this,but this don't work.

```
$url = "http://localhost/my_json.json";

$json_Data = file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);

print_r($json_Data);
```

And it doesn't print anything.

Help please.

Comment: Are you sure that your web server is correctly serving /my_json.json ?

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your php.ini file to enable requesting of URLS through `file_get_contents()` etc? See http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: allow_url_fopen is enabled.How to make sure that my web server is correctly serving ? what do you mean?

Comment: Point your browser to http://localhost/my_json.json and see if you receive the file. Also, if you are trying to POST (in the sense of HTTP POST), you might be better off with curl.

Comment: i second what Ramon says, cURL might be better

Comment: how to post it with curl

Comment: I mean, do you know that if you point a browser at http://localhost/my_json.json, it gets what you expect?

Comment: I create json object with php after submiting a form,and if I just print that json object I get this "{"my_json":"12345"}" so I'm pretty sure that is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Client:

```
<?php
$data = array('foo' => 'bar', 'red' => 'blue');


$ch = curl_init();
$post_values = array( 'json_data' => json_encode( $data ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/server.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_values);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
  echo 'Received raw data' . $data;
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Server (server.php):

```
<?php
$data = json_decode( $_POST['json_data'] );
// ... do something ...
header('Content-type: text/json');
print json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Ok,but I create dynamicly json object.Then point that object to another url another_url.'/my_json.json' and nothing retrive :(

Comment: Don't take me wrong, but what are you exactly trying to do? According to your question "I need to POST a json object with a HTTP POST request and to HANDLE RESPONSES.".

Comment: No,it is ok,maybe problem is that I send json object to https,and I need to retrive object from https

Comment: I need in php file to post object and to retreive it from https

Comment: This is the way that I create json obj                     $jsob = array();
                    $jsob['my_json'] = "12345"; $some_data = json_encode($jsob);

Comment: to echo it in url ?when I echo it,it display valid json object

Comment: No. This is a URL pointing to a FILE. You cannot POST against a FILE. At most you can GET the file. POST is done against an active element (php script like server.php, etc).

Comment: Ok,any example how to do this?I'm not php expert.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://localhost/my_json.json";

$json_Data = file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);

$new = json_decode($json_Data);

print_r($new);
```

I think that might do it

Comment: @user303832: Are you sure you have correct setup on your server? This code is 100% valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$jsonFile = 'http://localhost/my_json.json';
$jsonData = file_get_contents($jsonFile);
$phpData = json_decode($jsonData);
print_r($phpData);
```

Comment: Are you sure you can access http://localhost/my_json.json using your web browser?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be from the file_get_contents extraneous arguments :

- The 2d arg should be a boolean and is optional (default value is false)
- The 3rd arg is ok
- The 4th should be an integer, is optional (default value is -1)

So you should try `$json_Data = file_get_contents($url);`

Furthermore to view the data in your browser you should try with `header('Content-type: text/plain');` just before outputting with print_r() so that no processing will be made by your browser

To be sure there is really nothing sent to your browser, you may also try FireFox + FireBug to see HTTP replies...